# WPF MVVM How to combine many filters in ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a question that seems fairly easy but it seems i have a problem with it:

I have a data grid with some data:

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Candidates, IsAsync=True}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      CanUserAddRows="false">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Firstname}" Header="Imię" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Lastname}" Header="Nazwisko" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding commendation.Name}" Header="Polecenie" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now using mvvm and command I am applying some filters on those and it looks like:

```
    public CatalogViewModel()
    {
        this._catalog = new CatalogContexct();
        this._candidates = this._catalog.Candidates.Include("commendation").ToList();

        var candidates = new ListCollectionView(this._candidates);

        this.Candidates = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(candidates);

        this.FirstameCommand = new RelyCommand(FilterFirstname, param => this._canExecute);
        this.LastnameCommand = new RelyCommand(FilterLastname, param => this._canExecute);
        this.CommendationCommand = new RelyCommand(FilterCommendation, param => this._canExecute);
    }
```

And filters look like:

```
    public void FilterFirstname(object obj)
    {
        this.Candidates.Filter += item =>
        {
            Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;
            return candidate.Firstname.Contains(obj.ToString());
        };

        this.Candidates.Refresh();
    }

    public void FilterLastname(object obj)
    {
        this.Candidates.Filter += item =>
        {
            Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;

            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate.Lastname))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return candidate.Lastname.Contains(obj.ToString());
        };

        this.Candidates.Refresh();
    }

    public void FilterCommendation(object obj)
    {
        this.Candidates.Filter += item =>
        {
            Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate.commendation.Name))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return candidate.commendation.Name.Contains(obj.ToString());
        };

        this.Candidates.Refresh();
    }
```

Now this is basically working as intended BUT it work on each column separately so if I type name it will filter me a name and if I type last name it will filter me last name but it will override name so I wont get exact match for name and last name and I want to aggregate that filters.

Is there any way to aggregate that filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why it does not work?**

On each `FilterCommendation`, `FilterLastname`,`FilterFirstname` you are adding another delegate to `this.Candidates.Filter`. All of them will execute on `Refresh` but only result from last delegate will be returned. Consider following example:

```
Predicate<int> tmp = i => true;
tmp += i => i != 0;

Assert.AreEqual(true, tmp(1));
Assert.AreEqual(false, tmp(0));
```

It will allways return `i != 0` because it it the last predicate, but all of them will be executed. There is no 'and' between them.

**How you can accomplish your goals?**

You can create collection of filters and add or remove from it and refresh view. Full example below:

```
    Dictionary<string, Predicate<Candidate>> filters
        = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<Candidate>>();

    public CatalogViewModel()
    {
        ...

        Candidates.Filter = FilterCandidates;
    }

    private bool FilterCandidates(object obj)
    {
        Candidate c = (Candidate)obj;
        return filters.Values
            .Aggregate(true,
                (prevValue, predicate) => prevValue && predicate(c));
    }
    public void FilterFirstname(object obj)
    {
        string val = obj.ToString();
        AddFilterAndRefresh(
            "FirstName",
            candidate => candidate.Firstname.Contains(val));
    }

    public void FilterLastname(object obj)
    {
        string val = obj.ToString();
        AddFilterAndRefresh(
            "FirstName",
            candidate => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate.Lastname) && candidate.Lastname.Contains(val));
    }

    public void ClearFilters()
    {
        filters.Clear();
        Candidates.Refresh();
    }

    public void RemoveFilter(string filterName)
    {
        if (filters.Remove(filterName))
        {
            Candidates.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void AddFilterAndRefresh(string name, Predicate<Candidate> predicate)
    {
        filters.Add(name, predicate);
        Candidates.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: How would filters property look like?

Comment: I've just add the definition of `filters` field.

Comment: to use this for "Or" Filters I changed in the FilterCandidates's Aggregate Method the '&&' into '||' , and 'true' to 'false'. Also had to add a line before aggregating: filters.count==0 -> return true

Comment: instead of filters.Add(name, predicate); I would recommend filters[name] = predicate